# Custom Validation for jQuery Validate (two method in one)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I would like to know, how can I call another custom validation method of jquery validate in my method to validate some data. For sample, I have a field called 'Document ID' that can accept CPF or CNPJ (both are brazilians documents), and I need to validate it with jquery validate. I'm doing something like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("cpf", function(value, element) {
   // my validation for CPF Documents
}, "CPF inválido!");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("cnpj", function(value, element) {
   // my validation for CNPJ Documents
}, "CNPJ inválido!");
```

Both works fine when I have one field for each type but I have only one and I have to discovery what my user type on textfield and validate it, somethind like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("documentoId", function(value, element) {

   if (value.lenght <= 11) {
      // validation for CPF and change the message
   }
   else if (value.lenght <= 14) {
      // validation for CNPJ and change the message
   }

}, 'Documento inválido');
```

but I don't know how to call these custom functions (cpf and cnpj) inside my another function (documentId).

How can I do it? and how can I change the message inside my custom validation ?

Thank you!
Cheers!

I've posted my code in jsbin, if you want to look: http://jsbin.com/ijetex/5/edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("documentoId", function(value, element) {

   if (value.length <= 11) {
      jQuery.validator.methods.cpf.call(this, value, element);
   }
   else if (value.length <= 14) {
      jQuery.validator.methods.cnpj.call(this, value, element);
   }

}, 'Documento inválido');
```

Full example changing the error message

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("documento", function(value, element) {

  // remove pontuações
  value = value.replace('.','');
  value = value.replace('.','');
  value = value.replace('-','');
  value = value.replace('/','');

  if (value.length <= 11) {
    if(jQuery.validator.methods.cpf.call(this, value, element)){
      return true;
    } else {
      this.settings.messages.documento.documento = "Informe um CPF válido.";
    }

  }
  else if (value.length <= 14) {
    if(jQuery.validator.methods.cnpj.call(this, value, element)){
      return true;
    } else {
      this.settings.messages.documento.documento = "Informe um CNPJ válido.";
    }

  }

  return false;

}, "Informe um documento válido.");
```

Comment: Thanks rwilliams, do you know how can I change the message shown on validation message?

Comment: Updated my answer. I'm not sure what error message you want changed but give the above a shot.

Comment: Perfect rwilliamsn, it's everything I need! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("cnpj", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}?\/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}$/.test(value);
}, "Formato: 00.000.000/0000-00");
```

Comment: For only one CNPJ field, this works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

how about creating those function outside of the scope of the validation definition (i.e not using anonymous functions)?

```
function cpfValide(value,element) {
  //something
}

function cnpjValide(value,element){
  //something
}
jQuery.validator.addMethod("cpf", cpfValide, "CPF inválido!");


jQuery.validator.addMethod("documentoId", function(value, element) {
  return cpfValidate(value,element) || cnpjValidate(value,element);
//..
}
```

Comment: Thanks sJhonny, do you know how can I change the message shown on validation message?